# Find limit using Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4i}{n^2+i^2}$$

I know that we want $$\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)Δx_i$$
but I have trouble finding $$Δx_i$$ and was wondering if someone could help

Comment: $f(x)=\frac {4x} {1+x^{2}}, \Delta x_i=\frac  1n$.

Comment: Write $\frac{4i}{n^2+i^2}=\frac{n 4(i/n)}{n^2(1+(i/n)^2)}=\frac1n \frac{4x}{1+x^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{4 i}{n^2+i^2} &=4 \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\frac in}{1+\left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^2} \\
&=4 \int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2} d x\\&= 2\left[\ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right]_0^1\\&=2\ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$